# Swift How to know if one of my segment items is selected?

Tags: swift, xcode, uisegmentedcontrol

I have a segment and am wondering how to know if one of the items in the segment is selected. I do not care which one the user has chosen at this time.

**EDIT**

```
if variations.isSelected == false {
   print("none selected")
   return
}
```

Comment: segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex ?  segmentedControl.isSelected ?
segmented controller always selected one segment.

Comment: I still get false even when i have chosen of the items.

Comment: @Noby segmented control should only let you select 1. Are you using `UISegmentedControl`, or something else?

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo. I meant that I had chosen one of the items.

Comment: @Noby can you show your current code?

Comment: @RajaKishan I found this: *Set this property to -1 to turn off the current selection.*  in xcode hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Test for:

```
segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex != UISegmentedControl.noSegment
```